# Why does b+=(4,) work and b = b + (4,) doesn't work when b is a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

If we take `b = [1,2,3]` and if we try doing: `b+=(4,)`

It returns `b = [1,2,3,4]`, but if we try doing `b = b + (4,)` it doesn't work.

```
b = [1,2,3]
b+=(4,) # Prints out b = [1,2,3,4]
b = b + (4,) # Gives an error saying you can't add tuples and lists
```

I expected `b+=(4,)` to fail as you can't add a list and a tuple, but it worked. So I tried `b = b + (4,)` expecting to get the same result, but it didn't work.

Comment: I believe an answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904493/is-the-behaviour-of-pythons-list-iterable-documented-anywhere).

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897070/why-cant-i-add-a-tuple-to-a-list-with-the-operator-in-python

Comment: At first I misread this and tried to close it as too broad, then retracted it. Then I thought it had to be a duplicate, but not only could I not re-cast a vote, I pulled my hair out trying to find other answers like those. :/

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048664/understanding-pythons-builtins-operator-overloading-behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different behaviour for list.\_\_iadd\_\_ and list.\_\_add\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add)

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The problem with "why" questions is that usually they can mean multiple different things. I will try to answer each one I think you might have in mind.

**"Why is it possible for it to work differently?"** which is answered by e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841436/what-exactly-does-do-in-python). Basically, `+=` tries to use different methods of the object: `__iadd__` (which is only checked on the left-hand side), vs `__add__` and `__radd__` ("reverse add", checked on the right-hand side if the left-hand side doesn't have `__add__`) for `+`.

**"What exactly does each version do?"** In short, the `list.__iadd__` method does the same thing as `list.extend` (but because of the language design, there is still an assignment back).

This also means for example that

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a += [4] # uses the .extend logic, so it is still the same object
>>> b # therefore a and b are still the same list, and b has the `4` added
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = b + [5] # makes a new list and assigns back to b
>>> a # so now a is a separate list and does not have the `5`
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`+`, of course, creates a new object, but explicitly requires another list instead of trying to pull elements out of a different sequence.

**"Why is it useful for += to do this?** It's more efficient; the `extend` method doesn't have to create a new object. Of course, this has some surprising effects sometimes (like above), and generally Python is not really about efficiency, but these decisions were made a long time ago.

**"What is the reason not to allow adding lists and tuples with +?"** See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897070/why-cant-i-add-a-tuple-to-a-list-with-the-operator-in-python) (thanks, @splash58); one idea is that (tuple + list) should produce the same type as (list + tuple), and it's not clear which type the result should be. `+=` doesn't have this problem, because `a += b` obviously should not change the type of `a`.

Comment: Btw `|` for sets is a commuting operator but `+` for lists is not. For that reason I don't think the argument about type ambiguity is particularly strong. Since the operator does not commute why require the same for types? One could just agree that the result has the l.h.s.'s type. On the other hand, by restricting `list + iterator`, the developer is encouraged to be more explicit about their intent. If you want to create a new list that contains the stuff from `a` extended by the stuff from `b` there's already a way to do this: `new = a.copy(); new += b`. It's one more line but crystal clear.

Comment: The reason why `a += b` behaves differently than `a = a + b` is not efficiency. It's actually that Guido deemed the chosen behaviour _less_ confusing. Imagine a function receiving a list `a` as argument and then doing `a += [1, 2, 3]`. This syntax certainly _looks_ like it's modifying the list in place, rather than creating a new list, so the decision was made that it should behave according to what most people's intuition about the expected result. However, the mechanism also had to work for immutable types like `int`s, which led to the current design.

Comment: I personally think that the design is actually _more_ confusing than simply making `a += b` a shorthand for `a = a + b`, as Ruby did, but I can understand how we got there.

Answer (score 22):

They are not equivalent:

```
b += (4,)
```

is shorthand for:

```
b.extend((4,))
```

while `+` concatenates lists, so by:

```
b = b + (4,)
```

you're trying to concatenate a tuple to a list

Answer (score 15):

When you do this:

```
b += (4,)
```

is converted to this:

```
b.__iadd__((4,))
```

Under the hood it calls `b.extend((4,))`, `extend` accepts an iterator and this why this also work:

```
b = [1,2,3]
b += range(2)  # prints [1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

but when you do this:

```
b = b + (4,)
```

is converted to this:

```
b = b.__add__((4,))
```

accept only list object.

Answer (score 4):

From the official docs, for [mutable sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) both:

```
s += t
s.extend(t)
```

are defined as:

> extends `s` with the contents of `t`

Which is different than being defined as:

```
s = s + t    # not equivalent in Python!
```

This also means ***any sequence type will work for `t`***, including a tuple like in your example.

But it also works for ranges and generators! For instance, you can also do:

```
s += range(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

The "augmented" assignment operators like `+=` were introduced in Python 2.0, which was released in October 2000. The design and rationale are described in [PEP 203](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/). One of the declared goals of these operators was the support of in-place operations. Writing

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a += [4, 5, 6]
```

is supposed to update the list `a` *in place*. This matters if there are other references to the list `a`, e.g. when `a` was received as a function argument.

However, the operation can't always happen in place, since many Python types, including integers and strings, are *immutable*, so e.g. `i += 1` for an integer `i` can't possibly operate in place.

In summary, augmented assignment operators were supposed to work in place when possible, and create a new object otherwise. To facilitate these design goals, the expression `x += y` was specified to behave as follows:

- If `x.__iadd__` is defined, `x.__iadd__(y)` is evaluated.
- Otherwise, if `x.__add__` is implemented `x.__add__(y)` is evaluated.
- Otherwise, if `y.__radd__` is implemented `y.__radd__(x)` is evaluated.
- Otherwise raise an error.

The first result obtained by this process will be assigned back to `x` (unless that result is the `NotImplemented` singleton, in which case the lookup continues with the next step).

This process allows types that support in-place modification to implement `__iadd__()`. Types that *don't* support in-place modification don't need to add any new magic methods, since Python will automatically fall back to essentially `x = x + y`.

So let's finally come to your actual question – why you can add a tuple to a list with an augmented assignment operator. From memory, the history of this was roughly like this: The `list.__iadd__()` method was implemented to simply call the already existing `list.extend()` method in Python 2.0. When iterators were introduced in Python 2.1, the `list.extend()` method was updated to accept arbitrary iterators. The end result of these changes was that `my_list += my_tuple` worked starting from Python 2.1. The `list.__add__()` method, however, was never supposed to support arbitrary iterators as the right-hand argument – this was considered inappropriate for a strongly typed language.

I personally think the implementation of augmented operators ended up being a bit too complex in Python. It has many surprising side effects, e.g. this code:

```
t = ([42], [43])
t[0] += [44]
```

The second line raises `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`, [but the operation is successfully performed anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172263/a-mutable-type-inside-an-immutable-container) – `t` will be `([42, 44], [43])` after executing the line that raises the error.

Comment: Bravo! Having a reference to the PEP is especially useful. I added a link on the other end, to a previous SO question about the list-in-tuple behaviour. When I look back at what Python was like before 2.3 or so, it seems practically unusable compared to today... (and I still have a vague memory of trying and failing to get 1.5 to do anything useful on a very old Mac)

Answer (score 2):

Most people would expect X += Y to be equivalent to X = X + Y. Indeed, the Python Pocket Reference (4th ed) by Mark Lutz says on page 57 "The following two formats are roughly equivalent: X = X + Y , X += Y". However, the people who specified Python did not make them equivalent. Possibly that was a mistake which will result in hours of debugging time by frustrated programmers for as long as Python remains in use, but it's now just the way Python is. If X is a mutable sequence type, X += Y is equivalent to X.extend( Y ) and not to X = X + Y.

Comment: > Possibly that was a mistake which will result in hours of debugging time by frustrated programmers for as long as Python remains in use < - did you actually suffer because of this? You seem to be talking from experience. I'd very much like to hear your story.

Answer (score 1):

As it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446833/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-1-and-i-1-in-a-for-loop), if `array` doesn't implement `__iadd__` method, the `b+=(4,)` would be just a shorthanded of `b = b + (4,)` but obviously it's not, so `array` does implement `__iadd__` method. Apparently the implementation of `__iadd__` method is something like this:

```
def __iadd__(self, x):
    self.extend(x)
```

However we know that the above code is not the actual implementation of `__iadd__` method but we can assume and accept that there's something like `extend` method, which accepts `tupple` inputs.